# How do I bring back sharp edges on a Rounded Corner object in illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, illustrator-effects

As you see below, I've made a shape and I added round corners to it from `Effect > Stylize > Round Corners`, but now I want to bring it back to its original shape so I can make the edges less rounded.

Is there a way to clear the effect? I've tried `Object > Path > Clean Up` but it doesn't do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whip up the `Appearance` panel, either with `Window > Appearance` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>. In there, you should see the `Round Corners` effect be named.

[image: the Appearance panel with a Round Corners instance]

You can either drag the effect to the panel's waste bin and start anew, or click the effect's name to have its dialogue box pop up again, where you can edit the effect to your heart's content.

Comment: Thank you very much, i feel so stupid right now haha!! :p